A simple question on AP , only issue , answer does not match
Find the sum of natural numbers n that belong to the set [100,300] such that n is neither divisible by 4 nor by 6.
Book gives 26634 as the answer.
The sum of natural numbers from 100 to 300 is 40200.
The natural numbers in the set  [100,300] divisible by 4 starts with 100 and ends with 300 , total 51 numbers whose sum is 10200.
The natural numbers in the set  [100,300] divisible by 6 starts with 102 and ends with 300 , total 34 numbers whose sum is 6834.
The natural numbers in the set  [100,300] divisible by 24 starts with 120 and ends with 288, total 8 numbers whose sum is 1632.
So the answer is 40200 - 10200 -6834 + 1632 = 24798. The answer given is 26634.

What about the odd multiples of $12$ ?

LCM of 4,6 is 12.

108 is divisible by 4 and 6, but not 24.

Thank You.
I was somehow blindsided. Instead of LCM of 4,6 =12 i simply did 4*6.

You used inclusion-exclusion principle. However, intersection of multiples of $4$ and multiples of $6$ is multiples of $12$, not multiples of $24$. Multiples of $12$ in the set $[100, 300]$ is from $108$ to $300$, total $17$ numbers, so the sum is $3468$. So $40200-10200-6834+3468=26634$

Thank You. Need to take all multiples of 12 , not just multiples of 24 (which are even multiples of 12).
